# Substitute pattern in a column

Tags: awk, aix

I have a requirement to substitute pattern in a file from different file as input.

Lets say file1 content:

```
ab 10
bc 20
cd 30
de 40
```

file2:

```
server1;10 feb 2020;disk5;123455678;comment;10;1;desc;abcde3;987654
server1;10 feb 2020;disk6;123455678;comment;10;7;desc;abcde3;987654
server1;10 feb 2020;disk10;123455678;comment;20;4;desc;abcde3;987654
server1;10 feb 2020;disk1;123455678;comment;30;5;desc;abcde3;987654
server1;10 feb 2020;disk9;123455678;comment;20;4;desc;abcde3;987654
server1;10 feb 2020;disk2;123455678;comment;40;6;desc;abcde3;987654
server1;10 feb 2020;disk5;123455678;comment;30;8;desc;abcde3;987654
```

Here, as delimiter `;` in file2, I want to substitute column 6 with the matching value in file1.

i.e

```
server1;10 feb 2020;disk5;123455678;comment;**ab**;1;desc;abcde3;987654
```

I know its possible thru `awk` / `sed`. Can you please help?
Note: We do not use GNU version of `awk` / `sed` as its `AIX`.

Comment: please format your questions. It is hard to read.

Comment: Anything you tried yourself?

Comment: Do you actually want the `** ... **` around the replaced value, or was that purely for highlighting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficulty in this exercise is how to handle the different field separators in one and the same `awk` program.

Using GNU `awk`:

```
$ gawk 'FNR == NR { pat[$2] = $1; next } ($6 in pat) { $6 = pat[$6] } { print } ENDFILE { OFS = FS = ";" }' file1 file2
server1;10 feb 2020;disk5;123455678;comment;ab;1;desc;abcde3;987654
server1;10 feb 2020;disk6;123455678;comment;ab;7;desc;abcde3;987654
server1;10 feb 2020;disk10;123455678;comment;bc;4;desc;abcde3;987654
server1;10 feb 2020;disk1;123455678;comment;cd;5;desc;abcde3;987654
server1;10 feb 2020;disk9;123455678;comment;bc;4;desc;abcde3;987654
server1;10 feb 2020;disk2;123455678;comment;de;6;desc;abcde3;987654
server1;10 feb 2020;disk5;123455678;comment;cd;8;desc;abcde3;987654
```

Here, we start out reading the first file, populating the associative array `pat` with things that we'd like to replace in column 6 later.  The keys are the things we replace and the values are the things that we replace them with.

When GNU `awk` is done reading a file, it executes the `ENDFILE` block, if it exists (there is also a `BEGINFILE` block that could be useful under some circumstances).  `ENDFILE` and `BEGINFILE` are like "file local" `BEGIN` and `END` blocks.

Here, we use `ENDFILE` to change the input and output field separator to a semicolon.

When reading the second file, we simply test whether the data in the 6th field is available as a key in `pat` and if so, we replace its value with the value for that key.  All lines from the second file are printed, whether modified or not.

With a non-GNU `awk`, one could do like this:

```
$ awk 'FNR == NR { pat[$2] = $1; next } { OFS = FS = ";"; $0=$0 } ($6 in pat) { $6 = pat[$6] } { print }' file1 file2
server1;10 feb 2020;disk5;123455678;comment;ab;1;desc;abcde3;987654
server1;10 feb 2020;disk6;123455678;comment;ab;7;desc;abcde3;987654
server1;10 feb 2020;disk10;123455678;comment;bc;4;desc;abcde3;987654
server1;10 feb 2020;disk1;123455678;comment;cd;5;desc;abcde3;987654
server1;10 feb 2020;disk9;123455678;comment;bc;4;desc;abcde3;987654
server1;10 feb 2020;disk2;123455678;comment;de;6;desc;abcde3;987654
server1;10 feb 2020;disk5;123455678;comment;cd;8;desc;abcde3;987654
```

This is a bit inefficient, but what it does is that for each line in the second file, it sets `OFS` and `FS` to `;` and re-splits the input.

A slightly more efficient (but still ugly) variant would be to only set `OFS` and `FS` for the first line in the second file:

```
awk 'FNR == NR { pat[$2] = $1; next } FS != ";" { OFS = FS = ";"; $0=$0 } ($6 in pat) { $6 = pat[$6] } { print }' file1 file2
```

Comment: gawk didnt work for me..However, awk. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Palani Ah, yes, `gawk` is what GNU `awk` is called on most systems that has a different `awk` as the native one.

Comment: `$1=$1` doesn't re-split the input, `$0=$0` does that, so the non-gawk script you posted won't produce the output you posted (the first line will retain it's original $6 value). You should really use `FNR==1{ OFS = FS = ";"; $0=$0 }` instead to do the re-split correctly and only do it for 1 line instead of all of them.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm sorry, that's copied and posted directly from my terminal, so I did get that output. I do however note that both `mawk` and GNU `awk` fail to do the re-split for the current row, while BSD `awk` (`nawk`) does.  The user in the question uses `nawk` so they are fine. I will change it to work with GNU `awk` as well. The second issue (not re-splitting on every line) is already handled in the answer.

Comment: What you have now with `$0=$0` will work in any awk but if doing `$1=$1` caused whatever awk you were using to resplit the record into fields then that awk is not POSIX compliant. We already know that nawk is non-POSIX though (e.g. doesn't support character classes) so maybe just add this to the list of issues with nawk and why it's best avoided. IMHO `FNR==1` is clearer than testing `FS != ";"` but nbd.

Comment: @EdMorton _Where_ does `nawk` not support character classes? Note that `nawk` is at different levels of evolution on different platforms.  The regular expression support would come from the underlying regular expression libraries used.

Comment: Just look through the questions asked here (or google it) and see the cases where the issue was the lack of support of character classes in nawk. I don't have nawk on any system I use these days but, for example, when I last used Solaris a couple of years ago /usr/xpg4/bin/awk supported character classes while nawk on the same machine didn't.

Comment: @EdMorton Well, on modern Solaris systems, `nawk` supports character classes, as does the `awk` on AIX.  That is, if one believes the manuals.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all $6 values are covered in file1, try

```
awk 'FNR == NR {T[$2] = $1; next} {$6 = T[$6]} 1' file1 FS=";" OFS=";" file2
```

Comment: Wonderful..It works preciously.

Comment: Yup, this is how to do it. You should avoid all-upper-case variable names though to avoid potential clashes with builtin variable names.